# How to use Googlesheet formula for stock historical data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the Stock historical data
of the 1.)Stock Price 2.)Dividend & 3.)P/E ratio for the past 5 years.

Here is how I do for the Stock price for 2019

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("STOCK#", "close", DATE(2019,1,1), DATE(2019,12,31)),,2))
```

However, I cannot apply the same way for Dividend and P/E. May I know is there any way to achieve the same goal? Appreicated

Comment: Dividend and P/E of what?

Comment: @marikamitsos, for example, AAPL had four dividends in 2019 (.73+.77+.77+.77) =3.24
P/E: 22
Is it possible I could show it on googlesheet? Thanks

Comment: *"attribute is one of the **following** for historical data"* Please read more [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB)

Comment: @yes, I tried to replace "close" with "pe","eps", but all not working somehow. Thanks anyways